# Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') error for Chrome extension code

Tags: javascript

Please I am working on an extension to discover where apples are on a game website but I keep seeing this error causing it to not work properly. I have tried a few things but they just make the script to not work at all. The error is one line 142 with the attr() function:

> Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'split').

This is the full code:

```
var string_id = 1231414;
var page_title = document.title;
function sender_cheker(min, max) 
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

window.onload = function() {
        
        
        document.onclick = ({target}) => {
            page_title = document.title;
            console.log(page_title);
            if (page_title.indexOf('Apple Of Fortune') !== -1)
            {
                let parent = target;
                clas_name_parent = parent.parentNode.parentNode.className;
                if (clas_name_parent == "fortune-apple-bet__btn fortune-apple-btn fortune-apple-btn--bet")
                {
                    arry_apple_start = creete_new_str();
                    
                    $('.image_dop_for_provide').remove();
                    setInterval(print_result_apple,1000);
                }
            }
        }

        function creete_new_str()
        {
            var summ_true_apple      = new Array();
            var summ_false_apple     = new Array();
            var array_good_bed_apple = new Array();
            
            summ_true_apple[0] = 4;
            summ_true_apple[1] = 4;
            summ_true_apple[2] = 4;
            summ_true_apple[3] = 4;
            summ_true_apple[4] = 3;
            summ_true_apple[5] = 3;
            summ_true_apple[6] = 3;
            summ_true_apple[7] = 2;
            summ_true_apple[8] = 2;
            summ_true_apple[9] = 1;
            
            summ_false_apple[0] = 1;
            summ_false_apple[1] = 1;
            summ_false_apple[2] = 1;
            summ_false_apple[3] = 1;
            summ_false_apple[4] = 2;
            summ_false_apple[5] = 2;
            summ_false_apple[6] = 2;
            summ_false_apple[7] = 3;
            summ_false_apple[8] = 3;
            summ_false_apple[9] = 4;
    
            var napravlen = 0;
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                array_good_bed_apple[i] = new Array();
                if (napravlen == 0)
                {
                    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
                    {
                        var rand_var_for_this = coinToss();
                
                        if (rand_var_for_this == true)
                        {
                            if (summ_true_apple[i] > 0)
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 1;
                                summ_true_apple[i] --;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 0;
                                summ_false_apple[i] --;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (summ_false_apple[i] > 0)
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 0;
                                summ_false_apple[i] --;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 1;
                                summ_true_apple[i] --;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for(k=4;k>=0;k--)
                    {
                        var rand_var_for_this = coinToss();
                
                        if (rand_var_for_this == true)
                        {
                            if (summ_true_apple[i] > 0)
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 1;
                                summ_true_apple[i] --;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 0;
                                summ_false_apple[i] --;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (summ_false_apple[i] > 0)
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 0;
                                summ_false_apple[i] --;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array_good_bed_apple[i][k] = 1;
                                summ_true_apple[i] --;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if (napravlen == 0)
                    napravlen = 1;
                else
                    napravlen = 0;
            }
            
            return array_good_bed_apple;
        }
        
        function print_result_apple()
        {       
            var row_naw = $('div[class="fortune-apple-field__row fortune-apple-row fortune-apple-row--is-active"] button',0).attr('data-item').split('-');
            
            var ind = -1;
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    ind = 9;
                if (i == 1)
                    ind = 8;
                if (i == 2)
                    ind = 7;
                if (i == 3)
                    ind = 6;
                if (i == 4)
                    ind = 5;
                if (i == 5)
                    ind = 4;
                if (i == 6)
                    ind = 3;
                if (i == 7)
                    ind = 2;
                if (i == 8)
                    ind = 1;
                if (i == 9)
                    ind = 0;
                
                if (row_naw[0] == ind)
                {
                    $('.image_dop_for_provide').remove();
                    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
                    {
                        if (arry_apple_start[i][k] == 1)
                            $('button[data-item="'+ind+'-'+k+'"]').html('<img class="image_dop_for_provide" src="https://i.ibb.co/WtvVkbC/apple-t-f.png" style="opacity: 0.4; width:100%">');
                        else
                            $('button[data-item="'+ind+'-'+k+'"]').html('<img class="image_dop_for_provide" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZWfxcY9/apple-f-t.png" style="opacity: 0.4; width:100%">');
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        
        function coinToss() 
        {
            return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This message:

> Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ’split’)

indicates that the string you are trying to call `split(‘-')` on is `undefined`. That means that the result of `$('div[class="fortune-apple-field__row fortune-apple-row fortune-apple-row--is-active"] button',0).attr('data-item’)` must be `undefined`.

There’s not enough detail to diagnose further.

Comment: I have updated the question and added more detail @padeso , please check it out.

Comment: I think the problem must be with the `,0` at the end of the `$()` function. If that function has a second parameter, it’s meant to indicate the DOM element to use as context, and 0 doesn’t make sense for that. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: I tried removing the zero ,0 but it's still showing the same error. So that's not the problem.

Comment: Since this depends on the value of an attribute of a specific button in HTML, I can’t test this code, but try this: Put the following at the top of `print_result_apple()`.
let a = $('div[class="fortune-apple-field__row fortune-apple-row fortune-apple-row--is-active"] button’);
console.log(a);
let b = a.attr('data-item’);
console.log(b);
let c = b.split('-');
console.log(c);
Based on the error message, the value of `c` is going to be `undefined`. I think the value of `a` is going to turn out to be an array, too, which would explain it.

Comment: It's not working still